# Copy a column from one table to another in mysql (two different databases)

Tags: mysql, copy

I tried to copy a column from one table to another table (in two different databases)

I tried the following queries:

```
update des_db.mytable as des 
set col=  (select col from src_db.mytable as src where src.id = db.id)
```

and also joining these two tables.
In both solutions, I got the error "Total number of locks exceed the lock table size". 
I increased the "innodb_log_buffer_size to 32M and it doesn't work.

I want to know if there is any solution to do this.

IMPORTANT NOTE: the source table is actually my backup and it has the same number of rows as the other one has. (666,666 records)

Comment: I solved my problem by copying the whole backup table to my current database, but if I had changed some other fields and I want to retrieve only a specific column, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it should work:

```
UPDATE
des_db.mytable 
INNER JOIN src_db.mytable ON des_db.mytable.id = src_db.mytable.id
SET
des_db.mytable.col = src_db.mytable.col;
```

Unfortunately I can't test it right now, but I'm quite sure this works. Aliases should work also.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE database1.table1, database2.table1
SET database1.table1.columnA = database2.table1.columnA
WHERE database1.table1.id = database2.table1.id;
```